# Error 404 when Exporting Notebook from Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-lab, nbconvert

Jupyter Lab 4.0.2

When I try to save and export notebook as HTML or any other format I get a 404 error. Below is the output in from Anaconda Prompt.

```
[W 2023-08-04 11:47:19.166 ServerApp] 404 GET /nbconvert/HTML_NoInput/RTC%3ATest.ipynb?download=true (::1): No such file or directory: RTC:Test.ipynb
[W 2023-08-04 11:47:19.169 ServerApp] 404 GET /nbconvert/HTML_NoInput/RTC%3ATest.ipynb?download=true (0043a24c16a345a9a677f3d39b54e503@::1) 203.16ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/RTC%3ATest.ipynb
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling `nbconvert` but no luck. It seems to suggest that the notebook does not exist. I have tried on various notebooks stored in different file locations but I have the same issue. Any help anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your notebook? The error message suggests it is `RTC:Test`, with a colon `:` character. This can cause problems, you could try renaming the notebook to `RTCTest` for example.

Comment: Hi Marijn, thanks for your reply. The notebook is just called "Test" The RTC: seems to be something Jupyter is adding on. I believe this is related to the Real Time collaboration feature that was included in Jupyter 4 release but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yup, RTC breaks the download feature, even when you disable the collab-mode (see also the respective issue in the RTC github: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-collaboration/issues/183).

You can work around that issue by adding `--ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf=True` to the `c.Spawner.args` list and then manually deleting the "RTC:" from the URL when you get the 404 error.

Comment: Oh, and also maybe watch https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-collaboration/issues/151 and https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/2031